# Responsive design and image sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Q. What technique is the most efficient in terms of image load times and performance...?

Scenario 1.

Is it to load a different size image by using a media query, as below:

```
/* Smartphone */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   .img-page-1-img {
      background: url('../images/img-page-1-img-117.jpg') no-repeat;
      width: 117px;
      height: 77px;
   }
}
/* Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
   .img-page-1-img {
      background: url('../images/img-page-1-img-234.jpg') no-repeat;
      width: 234px;
      height: 154px;
   }
}
```

OR...

Scenario 2.

Load one single large image and use CSS to "stretch" and resize by setting the max-width property..?

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks....

Comment: Well, that loading a “large” image in any case, even if the page gets viewed on a really small screen, can’t be good for either load time or performance should be pretty obvious, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, an even more appropriate and/or responsive approach is to combine both. Use second `img` as a fallback and use media queries with `resolution` to specify the image:

```
img { ...low-res source }

@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
     img { ...hi-res source }
}
```

An agent that understands high-res may throw away first request and fetch hi-res image only; in the worst case there would be two requests. Everyone else will only fetch low-res source.

`resolution` is currently in [W3 Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#resolution)

Answer (score 1):

for responsive design we need to add this to get original image for large screens

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

and inside the media queries add like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
 width:117px;
}
```

and dont set height. you just control the image with parent by setting

> overflow:hidden; height:117px;

**

> and better to avoid background-images in responsive design, if you are
>   using you should need 4 to 5 images for each set. Try to use img tag

**

Answer (score 1):

Putting the different images in media queries won't work as some browsers will just preload all assets (even the ones that are no match for the current viewport).

See: http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=73 for a nice overview.

I'd go for div's with data attributes that contain a reference to the image to load. Check window width (or use matchMedia) with javascript and create the image on the fly.

For images that are really important (content wise / need to be indexed) you could add a small version initially and replace it with a high resolution version if the window is wide enough (or media query is matched using matchmedia).